# Word that means "impossibility"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> Our emotions aren't something we experience, but who we are. Hence the
>   [...] to get rid of them.

I thought of the word *futility* but I think it denotes more 'uselessness' than impossibility?

Comment: Some terms engineers love: *infeasibility*, *untenability*, *intractability*.

Comment: *Impossibility* is fine. But it should really be the impossibility of getting rid of them, and not the impossibility to get rid of them.

Comment: @RegDwigнt♦ What's the difference?

Comment: @janoChen - My friend, I'm having trouble accepting your premise. Emotional responses can be altered. In fact, "training and discipline required" inserted into your brackets would make more sense to me. (IMHO)

Comment: @Oldbag Oh, yeah. I finally left it as "Hence the
difficulty of getting rid of them."

Comment: @janoChen: the difference is that "the impossibility of" is idiomatic, and "the impossibility to" is not. COCA has 388 cites for the former, but only 3 for the latter. It just doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convey the idea of *something that is impossible to do* I'd rephrase as:

*Hence there is no way to get rid of them*!

Answer (score 1):

Futility is more "wasted action on something impossible to achieve", so it would be "Hence the futility of trying to get rid of them." in your context.

Comment: Hello nkjt. We're looking for answers backed up by authoritative quotes on ELU (not just correct ones) where possible.